# Gettind newly generated ID from user defined table type and inserting it into table with more data

Tags: sql-server

Sorry in advance for my naive heading

my problem is
I have a user-defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CldDetails] AS TABLE
(
ScheduledDate         DATETIME,
Amount                MONEY,
pmtTypeId             INT,
StatusId              INT,
UpdatedDate           DATETIME
reference             Varchar(50)
)
```

I am taking that table in my stored procedure as input parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AldAdd]
@clientDrafts                     [dbo].[CldDetails]  READONLY
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].CPTDetail (cppId, Date, Amount, pmtTypeId, StatusId,    
UpdatedDate)
SELECT ScheduledDate, Amount, pmtTypeId, StatusId, UpdatedDate FROM  
@clientDrafts;
END
```

Now my problem is that i need to insert a new record for each ID generated in above insert into another table with
reference field in @clientDrafts. Suppose there are 4 records in @clientDrafts. record no 1 has reference 10007.Now for first record new id 1 is generated then 
i need to get that newly generated id and reference 10007 from @clientDrafts into another table.

Comment: [Read about `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

Comment: For a multi-row `INSERT...SELECT`, use an `OUTPUT` clause on the statement to insert the generated and reference into a table variable.

Comment: @DanGuzman I can get the list of all generated Id's by using output into a temp table. Problem is how to co-relate those Id's with reference field in clientDrafts listing

Comment: @TechRon, I didn't see that you were not inserting the reference value into the target table so you can't do this with `INSERT..SELECT` as I suggested. However, you can with `MERGE`, assuming you are using a modern version of SQL Server. I'll add an answer with an example.

Comment: @DanGuzman I am using SQL server 2014. I would really appreciate if you can guide me here with merge.

Comment: @TechRon, I added an answer. It's a good idea to add the version-specific tag to your question since the best solution may vary by version.

Comment: @DanGuzman I will keep a note to add version-specific tag from now onwards..Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not inserting the `reference` value into the target table, it will not be available in the `OUTPUT` clause of `INSERT...SELECT` to correlate the generated `cppId` column `IDENTITY` value with the `reference` value. However, you can do this by using `MERGE` instead, assuming you are using a modern SQL Server version.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AldAdd]
    @clientDrafts [dbo].[CldDetails] READONLY
AS

MERGE [dbo].CPTDetail AS target
USING (SELECT
      ScheduledDate
    , Amount
    , pmtTypeId
    , StatusId
    , UpdatedDate
    , reference
    FROM @clientDrafts) AS source ON 0 = 1 --unconditional inserts
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
        Date
        , Amount
        , pmtTypeId
        , StatusId
        , UpdatedDate
        )
    VALUES (
        source.ScheduledDate
        , source.Amount
        , source.pmtTypeId
        , source.StatusId
        , source.UpdatedDate
    )
OUTPUT
        inserted.cppId --generated identity value
      , source.ScheduledDate
      , source.Amount
      , source.pmtTypeId
      , source.StatusId
      , source.UpdatedDate
      , source.reference
      INTO dbo.AnotherTable;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:
Use @@IDENTITY for newly created record this will give you id for last inserted record I will give you sample SQL script please try to modify that according to your tables.
One more this you required using cursor fetch record one by one.

```
DECLARE @Id decimal(18,0)
    DECLARE @newId decimal(18,0)
DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR SELECT pId FROM  temp

OPEN Cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Id

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )

BEGIN

 --------------Insert into table 1
                INSERT INTO temp (pId,Name)
                SELECT pId ,Name from @clientDrafts where pId = @Id 

SET @newId = @@IDENTITY

 --------------Insert into table 1
                INSERT INTO temp2
                (Id,Name,pId)
                Select Id,Name,pId=@newId from temp2 
                    where 
                        pId = @Id

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Id

END

CLOSE Cur 
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

please try this it will help you.

Comment: The above won't work..Its logic is not pertaining to the problem I explained. Your solution is picking up generated id and inserting it in another table. My problem is that i am inserting a list of records with user defined table type and i need to pick the generated ID and then insert into another table with the value of reference field in user-defined table type list. How to co-relate generated id with its reference ID is the actual problem.